# disable scrollable feature of recycler view in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

Recycler view has scroll feature automatically . i want to disable that auto scroll. i want to use scrollview for scrolling .

Answer (score 0):

> You should override the layoutManager of your recycleView for this. This way it will only disable scrolling, none of the other functionalities. You will still be able to handle click or any other touch events. For example:-

```java
public class CustomGridLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;

    public CustomGridLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setScrollEnabled(boolean flag) {
        this.isScrollEnabled = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        //Similarly you can customize "canScrollHorizontally()" for managing horizontal scroll
        return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically();
    }
}
```

Comment: i got one problem , when i am doing isScrollEnabled = false ;                                                                    it does not show all elements of recyclerview . it only shows some element .

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using nested scroll view.